# Recursively printing numbers as symmetric sequences

Tags: java, recursion, numbers, symmetric

I want to print entered numbers as **symmetric sequences** without zero using recursive functions.

Let's take a method called `void demo(int n)`.

#### Example

For `n=5` it should print:

```
"5 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 5 "
```

#### Problem

I can print `"5 4 3 2 1 "`.

My recursive function is `demo(n-1)` so I can print.
When function reached to `n=0`, I think it must redound the values. But I couldn't write anything inside of the if block.

#### Code

```
public class demo {

    void demo(int n) {
        if ( n == 0) 
        {
            // tried to write something here         
        }
        System.out.println(n);
        return demo(n-1);   
    }
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using recursion to print symmetric integer sequences that count down and then up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823511/using-recursion-to-print-symmetric-integer-sequences-that-count-down-and-then-up)

Comment: Can you write the full solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```java
public class demo {
    void demo(int n) {
        System.out.println(n);

        if (n > 1) {
            demo(n - 1);
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

It's not tail recursive, but this is a case where recursion is simpler than iteration.

If you iterate then you would need two loops:

1. One loop counting down from `n` to `1`.
2. Another loop counting up from `2` to `n`.

However, using recursion we can simply count down from `n` to `1` and print each number and then print the number again after the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I find generally easier to directly tackle the end condition at the beginning of the recursive function, then perform the right processing.

```
public class demo {
    void demo(int n) {
        // displays the number once then goes back forward
        if(n <= 1) {
            System.out.print(n + " ");
            return;
        }    
        
        // displays the number once, then all the numbers below it, then again the number
        System.out.print(n + " ");
        demo(n - 1);
        System.out.print(n + " ");
    }
}
```

My solution is basically the reversed version of the accepted one, but I would say that it is clearer in a recursive context to actually handle the end condition with a `return` rather than continuing the processing while a condition remains true.